# What is the difference between Docker Daemon and Docker Engine?

Tags: docker, containers, docker-machine

Can some one explain the difference between the two, which contains the docker runtime?

Answer (score 19):

Docker Engine is the core product of Docker, including its daemon (dockerd) as well as its CLI (docker). Docker Daemon is simply a part of Docker Engine.

Quoting the [Docker engine overview](https://docs.docker.com/engine/) page:

> Docker Engine is an open source containerization technology for
> building and containerizing your applications. Docker Engine acts as a
> client-server application with:
>
> - A server with a long-running daemon process dockerd.
> - APIs which
>   specify interfaces that programs can use to talk to and instruct the
>   Docker daemon.
> - A command line interface (CLI) client docker.

Answer (score 9):

They are the same, and neither.

The Docker daemon and engine refer to the same `dockerd` process. Docker itself doesn't contain the container runtime in the `dockerd` binary anymore. That was moved out to the [runc](https://github.com/opencontainers/runc) project long ago, and you can swap in other runtimes for your own use cases.

Between that runtime and the docker daemon is [containerd](https://github.com/containerd/containerd) which is used to manage the images, containers, and filesystem layers. So you can think of the docker daemon as being broken apart into various microservices.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a picture, which I find easier to understand than words. I found it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rOTqprHv1YE&t=5s).

[image]

Comment: It is not clear even from the entire video